# Acess a long javascript file from the computer of the user

Tags: jquery, html, installation

I have my company website for some accounting and other works. I have a javascript file which is of 126KB. The website is to be viewed in only 5 PC's. So, I find it useless in downloading the javascript file as well as the jQuery file. Is there any way by which I can access the remote javascript files which I will store in the 5 PC's so that the page load time is reduced a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! There is a way. Few days ago I was also searching for the same answer. But, unfortunately, I did not get a proper answer. So, I did a lot of research and found the remedy.
First of all, lucky you including the tag "html5" in your question as you can do it **ONLY** using HTML5.
You can do it by just making a cache of your javascript file in the local computer. Just include the following lines in your code:-

```
<html <!-- add this => -->  manifest="a_file.appcache">
```

and in your a_file.appcache file include this:-

```
CACHE MANIFEST
demo_time.js
img_logo.gif

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
/html/ /offline.html
```

This is only a demo. You must learn application cache. Just check out the tutorials at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp and at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/ . So, with application cache, you only would have to download the javascript file once in each of the computer and then you can access it offline....easy

Comment: whoa that was a quick answer

Comment: Of course, only a [subset of browsers support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes but since there are only a limited number of users, you can make them use a browser that supports HTML5

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same result can be achieved by using [Expires](http://www.smartlabsoftware.com/howto/expires-header.php) correctly.  With a reasonably long expire time the end result will be nearly the same performance-wise, and it works on just about any browser you can imagine.